# Using wildcard in GNU Make pattern rule

Tags: make, gnu-make

Assume `doc.pdf` is the target.

The following rule triggers a regeneration of `doc.pdf` whenever `doc.refer` is updated, but is also happy when `doc.refer` does not exist at all:

```
doc.pdf: doc.mom $(wildcard doc.refer)
    pdfmom -e -k < $< > $@
```

However the following pattern rule does not accomplish the same (the PDF is generated correctly, but a rebuild is not triggered when changing `doc.refer`):

```
%.pdf: %.mom Makefile $(wildcard %.refer)
    pdfmom -e -k < $< > $@
```

I suspect that the `wildcard` command is executed before the `%` character is expanded. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The GNU Make function `wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) takes a shell globbing pattern and expands it to the files matching that pattern.  The pattern `%.refer` does not contain any shell globbing patterns.

You probably want something like

```
%.pdf: %.mom %.refer
        pdfmom -e -k < $< > $@

%.pdf: %.mom
        pdfmom -e -k < $< > $@
```

The first target will be invoked for making PDF files when there's a `.mom` *and* a `.refer` file available for the base name of the document.  The second target will be invoked when there isn't a `.refer` file available.

The order of these targets is important.

Answer (score 3):

You maybe able to use [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.pdf: %.mom Makefile $$(wildcard %.refer)
    pdfmom -e -k < $< > $@
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU Make evaluate all functions in order to generate internal representation of pattern rules.

Thus `$(wildcard %.refer)` evaluated to empty string for your rule.

The only way to achieve your goal is to exploit rule ordering like  **Kusalananda**'s solution suggest `(info "(make)Pattern Match")`:

```
10.5.4 How Patterns Match

   It is possible that more than one pattern rule will meet these
criteria.  In that case, 'make' will choose the rule with the shortest
stem (that is, the pattern that matches most specifically).  If more
than one pattern rule has the shortest stem, 'make' will choose the
first one found in the makefile.
```